# Why doesn't Elasticsearch Ingest accept a grok pattern that Logstash does?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, escaping, logstash

I have the following grok pattern that works in Logstash and in the Grok debugger in Kibana.

```
\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:req_time}\] %{IP:client_ip} (?:%{IP:forwarded_for}|\(-\)) (?:%{QS:request}|-) %{NUMBER:response_code:int} %{WORD}:%{NUMBER:request_length:int} %{WORD}:%{NUMBER:body_bytes_sent:int} %{WORD}:(?:%{QS:http_referer}|-) %{WORD}:(?:%{QS:http_user_agent}|-) (%{WORD}:(\")?(%{NUMBER:request_time:float})(\")?)?"
```

I am trying to create a new ingest pipeline via the PUT method, but I get an error that contains:

```
    "type": "parse_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to parse content to map",
    "caused_by": {
        "type": "i_o_exception",
        "reason": "Unrecognized character escape '[' (code 91)\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper@61326735; line: 7, column: 25]"
    }
```

Comment: I had a newline at the end of pattern which was causing it to fail during file ingest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch requires that grok patterns used in pipelines submitted using the PUT method are properly escaped JSON, while Logstash patterns use different escaping.

That includes preceding brackets with double backslashes (`\\[`) and double quotes with triple backslashes (`\\\"`). The working pattern (after running through a JSON escaping tool) is:

```
\\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:req_time}\\] %{IP:client_ip} (?:%{IP:forwarded_for}|\\(-\\)) (?:%{QS:request}|-) %{NUMBER:response_code:int} %{WORD}:%{NUMBER:request_length:int} %{WORD}:%{NUMBER:body_bytes_sent:int} %{WORD}:(?:%{QS:http_referer}|-) %{WORD}:(?:%{QS:http_user_agent}|-) (%{WORD}:(\\\")?(%{NUMBER:request_time:float})(\\\")?)?
```